# Appcelerator Cloud Services - Find string in photos object custom field

Tags: titanium, cloud, appcelerator, photos, search

I'm having trouble using the query/search capabilities of Cloud.photos, more specifically, finding a way of search for a string in title field.

After reading this: http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/guide/search_query, I was able to perform querys with $regex:

```
where: {title: {'$regex' :  '^' + searchterm}},
```

But works only if the search term is in the beginning of the title, and it's case sensitive (I'm obviously a complete regex newbie).

Also tried search API with no luck. I didn't find which were the searchable fields.

So, I'm in some sort of dead end. I'm looking for a SQL like similar funcionality, where I can perform a search of a term and if matches regardless of the position and whether it is upper or lower case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

see the release notes here for 11 Apr 2013

http://docs.appcelerator.com/cloud/latest/#!/guide/acs_releasenotes

it cannot be done any other way because the query would be too inefficient